# Cross compiling ffmpeg: error while adding libopus: undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'

Tags: ffmpeg, compile, cmake, opus

I have set in the cmake file the following:

```
set(STACK_PROTECTOR_SUPPORTED 0)
set(FORTIFY_SOURCE_SUPPORTED 0)
```

However ffmpeg configure fails at this point: (from config log)

```
    ...
    ...
    rnx/development_exp_all/winbuilds/lib -o /tmp/ffconf.sp6O6kif/test.exe /tmp/ffconf.sp6O6kif/test.o -lopus -lm
    /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: \
 /home/rnx/development_exp_all/winbuilds/lib/libopus.a(PLC.c.obj):PLC.c:(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'
    /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: \
 /home/rnx/development_exp_all/winbuilds/lib/libopus.a(bands.c.obj):bands.c:(.text+0x506e): undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'
    /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: \
 /home/rnx/development_exp_all/winbuilds/lib/libopus.a(decode_core.c.obj):decode_core.c:(.text+0x284): undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'
```

The error shown is

`ERROR: opus not found using pkg-config`

But this is not because pkg-config fails to find it.

```
$ pkg-config --list-all
opus Opus - Opus IETF audio codec ( build)
x264 x264 - H.264 (MPEG4 AVC) encoder library
x265 x265 - H.265/HEVC video encoder
aom  aom - Alliance for Open Media AV1 codec library v3.7.0-577-gfb09b4c854.
```

The error I believe is due to `undefined reference to __memcpy_chk'`

How do I set cmake to avoid this error